# how to do git rebase effectively

Tags: git, github

I have been following this path to push my changes to `feature-branch`

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
<make changes and commit>
git push origin feature-branch
...
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
<resolve conflicts>
git push origin feature-branch -f
```

Everyone now and then, the problem i face is that my PullRequest ends up having commits from other branch (which has already been merged to master).

To avoid this, i have started to use `git merge master` but it adds `Merge` commit which i am not liking.

Can someone help me understand how can i avoid commits from other branches appearing in my branch?

Comment: That's not how it is supposed to work ;)
I do a similar workflow and have never experienced this. Do you have any information about the commits that are appearing? Do they have a different commit hash?
The workflow I use is just `git fetch; git rebase origin/master` whilst still in `feature branch`

Comment: "the problem i face is that my PullRequest ends up having commits from other branch (which has already been merged to master)" Are you opening these pull requests to master or to another branch?

Comment: You need to track down where those other commits are coming from. Off-hand, I can think of the following causes 1) Someone is rewriting the history of `master` with a force push (HUGE red flag). Other people on your team would experience the same problems, and likely with the same commits. Whomever is doing this is in the wrong and needs to change. 2) You're merging other branches into your feature branch. This one is on you - this isn't allowed in the `rebase` process you're using. 3) Your `feature-branch` isn't based on master.

Do any of these sound likely to you?

Comment: @DaveShaw - To your point, I actually instruct my colleagues to rarely ever checkout develop or master so they don't accidentally branch/rebase with an old version of it. Just fetch and use origin all the time!

Comment: have a look at https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67 which describes one choice which uses a `rerere` cache to remember your resolutions yet maintain a fixed branch start point, and at the same time being 'merge' ready. Also you didn't say what your upstream 'origin/master' maintainer used as their preferred workflow (always a good start;-).